# ¿Como ocultar en este caso la barra de superior de un visor pdf?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, pdf

Este es mi controllador

```
if (!response.CodError) {
    $scope.datosImprimir.Resultado.PDF = response.Valor;
    $scope.contenido = $sce.trustAsHtml('<embed width="100%" alt="pdf" src="data:application/pdf;base64,' + response.Valor + '" class="pdfImprimir" pluginspage="http://www.adobe.com/products/acrobat/readstep2.html">');

} else {
    bootbox.alert($scope.datos.Errores[response.CodError]);
 }
```

y mi vista:

```
<div id="contenedor" ng-bind-html="contenido"></div>
```

Eh buscando por allí y eh probado todo lo que encontre pero nada me sirvió

Comment: Especifica a que te refieres con la barra superior y en que caso es que quieres ocultarla

Comment: Pues la barra que se despliega arriba y tiene los iconos de descargar, guardar, girar. Quiero que solo se vea el pdf y nada mas

Comment: Prueba esto : `document.getElementsByClassName('toolbar')[0].remove()`

Comment: Chrome no me muestra la barra de herramientas; IE y Firefox, sí. Parece que lo que quieres es modificar el comportamiento normal del lector de PDF del navegador del usuario, y no sé si eso es recomendado o incluso posible.

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro Si es posible en algunos navegadores, usando parámetros en la query que hace referencia al PDF, con `&toolbar=0` se oculta. En el caso del OP está usando base64 encoding en la fuente lo que lo vuelve más complicado. Creo que la solución es desechar el base64 para almacenar los pdfs.

Comment: @devconcept probé lo de `toolbar=0` antes de escribir mi comentario y sólo me funcionó en Chrome (por eso en mi comentario ponía que Chrome no me mostraba la barra mientras los otros sí). Pero tienes razón, debería haber sido más claro en cuanto a eso.

Comment: De hecho se puede a medias, ya que todo lo mostrado en el navegador normalmente el usuario puede modificarlo.

Comment: @JoseHermosillaRodrigo no me funciono lo que comentaste